# Variable is already declared as private

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have an entity framework model (built using database first)  which I have just updated from the database.  I now have a whole series of errors in the model, typical of which is;

`_Addresses` is already declared as `Private _Addresses AS System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet(of Address)` in this class.  If I then double click on the error in the error list it takes me to the following block of codein the Model's designer.vb file.

```
   ''' <summary>
''' No Metadata Documentation available.
''' </summary>
Public ReadOnly Property Addresses() As ObjectSet(Of Address)
    Get
        If (_Addresses Is Nothing) Then
            _Addresses = MyBase.CreateObjectSet(Of Address)("Addresses")
        End If
        Return _Addresses
    End Get
End Property

Private _Addresses As ObjectSet(Of Address)
```

I can see nothing different here to what was there originally, but the project will not build successfully anymore.  Can anyone suggest why this may be and what it is that has happened to cause the errors to appear.

More importantly can anyone suggest how one goes about rectifying this without resorting to rebuilding the entity data model from scratch.  The data model is in a separate project so it could be rebuilt but it has undergone a lot of customisation so I would prefer not to go down that route.

Thanks for any advice that you can offer.

Comment: VB.NET automatically creates a hidden backing field of all auto implemented properties. _Addresses already exists. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx ). Are you sure the project looks the same as before?

Comment: Hi Alex, than you for your thoughts and the link. Fortunately I had a sufficiently recent backup of the entity model to restore it.  Checking the designer code file for the sample I posted in my original question reveals it to be identical.  The only thing I can point to as being different to when I have updated from the database on previous occasions was the fact that I did not immediately rebuild the model.  It gets me no closer to knowing why this occurred but perhaps may help others along the way at some point in the future.